# How to get data passed from PUT method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am creating an API for Laravel. I use the PUT method for updating data.

I send data with Postman using the PUT method. In my controller, I got an empty array. How to access the passed data?

In my route, I have:

```
Route::put('vehicletypes/{id}','API\VehicletypeController@update');
```

In my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

print_r($request->all()); exit;

}
```

[image]

How to get the data passed in **PUT** method?

Comment: except `PUT` rest of functions are working from this controller?

Comment: Can you tell what header value you have set?

Comment: i set authorization only @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: ok, and except PUT rest of functions are working from this same controller?

Comment: try `x-www-form-urlencoded` for fun

Answer (score 10):

You are getting empty response because PHP have some security restrictions against [`PUT`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php). But Laravel have a workaround for this.
So, to solve this you have to send a `POST` request from Postman instead, with a `POST` param `_method` with value `PUT`. And that should work.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel cheats because html forms only support GET and POST, but it does understand a real PUT/PATCH request.

The problem looks like lies in Symfony it can't parse the data if it's multipart/form-data, as **an alternative try using x-www-form-urlencoded content disposition**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18184541)

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi how so? `try using x-www-form-urlencoded ...` seems to be an answer to me

Comment: Your response is more of a suggestion than an answer, I suggest updating your post to explain exactly and with code how to "try using x-www-form-urlencoded..." as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function putUpdate(Request $request, $id){

print_r($request->all()); exit;

}
```

And change route too,

```
Route::put('vehicletypes/{id}','API\VehicletypeController@putUpdate');
```

Comment: As I said earlier, just try `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

Checked "x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "form-data" under body tab in the Postman, the put methood will work as well...

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody is giving clear explanation
at first put method field of

```
{{method_field('put')}}
```

as your router uri is that is displayed using command

```
php artisan router:list
```

of update method is put/patch so first add

```
{{method_field('put')}}
```

and field in your form should be the same

```
<form action="{{route('posts.update',$post->id)}}" method="post">
```

after adding the csrf_toke form will be working. and final shape would be as below of form.

```
<form action="{{route('posts.update',$post->id)}}" method="post" >
  {{method_field('put')}}
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
            <!-- Name input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Title</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="name" name="title" type="text" value="{{$post->title}}" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>          


    <!-- Message body -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="body">
      Body</label><br>
      <div class="col-md-9">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="body" rows="5">
    {{$post->body}}
    </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <!-- Form actions -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-9 text-right col-md-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>
        <a href="{{Route('posts.index')}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </div>         
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following link will resolve the issue to get the request form data plus the images. 
If you are working on Laravel, you can easily parse and bind the form params in the \Illuminate\Http\Request Instance

Simply just get the ParseInputStream Class from the link below: 
[Class ParseInputStream.php](https://gist.github.com/devmycloud/df28012101fbc55d8de1737762b70348)

Create another Validation Rule Class in Laravel optional but not required,

```
class NoteUpdateRequest extends Request {

public function all($keys = null)
{
    if(strtolower($this->getMethod())=='put' && preg_match('/multipart\/form-data/', $this->headers->get('Content-Type')) or
        preg_match('/multipart\/form-data/', $this->headers->get('content-type')))
    {
        $result = [];
        new ParseInputStream($result);
        $result = array_merge($result, $this->route()->parameters());
        $this->request->add($result);
    }

    return parent::all($keys);
}

public function rules()
{
    dd($this->all());
    return [
        'noteId'        => 'required|integer|exists:notes,id',
        'title'         => 'required|string|max:200',
        'note'          => 'required|string|min:10|max:2000'
    ];
 }
}
```

[image]

I hope it resolved what you want to achieve, using PUT or PATCH method along with Form Params

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this isn't a laravel (or symfony, or any other framework) issue, it's a limitation of PHP.

That said, I managed to find [this PECL extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/apfd). I'm not very familiar with pecl, and couldn't seem to get it working using pear. but I'm using CentOS and Remi PHP which has a yum package.

I believe there are other packages in various flavours of linux and I'm sure anybody with more knowledge of pear/pecl/general php extensions could get it running on windows or mac with no issue.

I ran `yum install php-pecl-apfd` and it literally fixed the issue straight away (well I had to restart my docker containers but that was a given).

That is, `request->all()` and `files->get()` started working again with PATCH and PUT requests using `multipart/form-data`.

Ergo, I managed to get my api playing nicely with my front-end without adding any quirks (that would need to be relayed to anybody developing front-end solutions) or breaking RESTful conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel cannot parse PUT data, you can use streams to retrieve data directly:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($input, $data); // Parsing form
print_r($data); // Your data
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input