# Laravel CRUD with Resources API Controller not trigger Request data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just starting to learn here using the Resource Controller API at Laravel.

In this case I managed to do all the commands except Update data.

It seems that the Request Data in this update method is not called and remains empty.

Here's my File Controller.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;
use Image;
use App\Model\LoadScreen;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\ApiController;

class LoadScreenController extends ApiController
{
    protected $request;
    protected $posted;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->posted = $this->request->except('_token', '_method');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $splash = LoadScreen::findByHashedId($id);
        if ($splash) {
            $data = $request->all();
            if ($this->request->hasFile('image')) {
                $image = $data['image'];

                $filename = md5($image . time()) . '.png';
                $data['image'] = Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, file_get_contents($image));

                $path = 'assets/img/loadScreen/' . $filename;
                $intervention = Image::make($image)->fit(1080, 2248, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path);

                $data['image'] = $path;
            }
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $this->posted[$key] = $value;
            }
            $splash->save($this->posted);
            return $this->successResponse('success', $splash, 200);
        }
        return $this->errorResponse('failed', 400);
    }
}
```

And Route file.

```php
        Route::resource('loadScreen', 'LoadScreenController');
```

Route List.

```php
|        | GET|HEAD                         | admin/v1/loadScreen                           | loadScreen.index                             | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@index
|        | POST                             | admin/v1/loadScreen                           | loadScreen.store                             | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@store
|        | GET|HEAD                         | admin/v1/loadScreen/create                    | loadScreen.create                            | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@create
|        | DELETE                           | admin/v1/loadScreen/{loadScreen}              | loadScreen.destroy                           | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@destroy 
|        | GET|HEAD                         | admin/v1/loadScreen/{loadScreen}              | loadScreen.show                              | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@show
|        | PUT|PATCH                        | admin/v1/loadScreen/{loadScreen}              | loadScreen.update                            | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@update
|        | GET|HEAD                         | admin/v1/loadScreen/{loadScreen}/edit         | loadScreen.edit                              | App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\LoadScreenController@edit
```

I have tried to return the value of the Request. But still there is no Request anything from the API.

I'm here using the PUT Method in Postman to update data.

Here I use Postman to test it.

I hope someone can explain why that happened.

Thank you very much

Comment: what is the url you put in postman to update the value

Comment: like this `http://project.pro/admin/v1/loadScreen/ZQ5N9nX2wAb7aVj` In this case only 4 Index, Create, Edit, Update, Destroy that I use.

Comment: `Route::resource('loadScreen', 'LoadScreenController');` is in `Route->api` or `Route->web`, if it is in api then you have to put `/api` in the url

Comment: then try `http://project.pro/api/admin/v1/loadScreen/ZQ5N9nX2wAb7aVj`

Comment: I'm here using the Custom RouteServiceProvider and going to `Route-> admin`

Comment: What's in the request body in Postman?

Comment: Only image and status with form-data

Comment: can you check whether the `update()` is triggered or not? like `return 'yeah..'`

Comment: If I only return the text in this update it works. But when I return this request there is no data request

Comment: Are you trying to return the image @MochamadAkbar ? You cannot send the image using PUT method.  Use POST request but add ***__method =PUT***. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694722/how-to-get-data-passed-from-put-method

Comment: @Syazany If only in this laravel it works. However I used it on **Vuejs SPA** with no luck. Because `Route loadScreen/{loadScreen}` with **POST** method is not found when I use `axios.post`

Comment: @MochamadAkbar I assume you use form data to send the image using Vue correct? So you need to make a post request but add this to your form data formData.append("_method", "PATCH"); It should work

Comment: @Syazany Well I will try it first. Thanks .